# Limit QWidget size

Tags: c++, linux, qt, window

Let's say I have an wall where user can have only `N` windows. I should restrict the user from setting one window over another. He can move, resize them but he cannot overlap them. To ignore the invalid moves I am catching the `moveEvents` and if the `event->pos()` is an invalid position I reset the geometry to the `event->oldPos()`. Well this approach is not working for `resizeEvent`. 
Why I can't use same approach on resize? 
How can I solve this problem? 
**P.S** Setting maximumSize and minimumSize is not a good idea, it's to consuming because of my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

When a user resized a window or `resize` is called Qt sets `Qt::WA_WState_ConfigPending` flag to `true` and starts internal resize operations. During these operations you receive `resizeEvent`. If you try to call `resize` there `Qt` just checks that the flag is set and ignores new resize until previous one is finished, however it sends `resizeEvent` again with the same data and you get into an endless recursion.

You can use this trick to overcome the check:

```
void widget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* e)
{
    if (e->size().width() > 800)
    {
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_WState_ConfigPending, false);
        resize(e->oldSize());
    }
}
```

However, you still get blinking of the window, because it's already resized when you get `resizeEvent`.  Actually OS resizes a window and then sends `WM_SIZE` message to a window to handle the change, that's why you have to deal with the result of the resize operation.

Comment: I understood the logic, but still unable to solve the problem. Last resizeEvent I am getting is the event I sent(after checking) but the window I see has the wrong size. :(

Comment: What do you meen by 'wrong size'? I corrected the example to the full code of `resizeEvent` which works for me. When you try to resize a window more than 800px it stops resizing. Could you try this code and get back with your results?

Comment: Yes it stops almost at 800(actually it's 800+) and if you try after that to increase the width it will allow you to.

Comment: In this case my suggestion is to avoid using `oldSize`. In the example above you can do it with `resize(QSize(799, e->size().height()))`.

Comment: I am sorry, on unity it's resizing corectly and I got an strange view after 800 but at the end of resize window looks good. Problem is that I work on KDE and here at the end of resize(i mean at mouse release) the window I see is not resized to the 800 it still has the width where i released the mouse click. Is there a way I could catch events before execution and decide if this event should be done or ignored?

Comment: Do you use KDE on Windows?

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought that your question is tagged `windows` but it was just `window`) Added tag `linux`. Probably `linux` experts will be able to correct my solution to work on `linux` with KDE.

Comment: @StraticiucVicu Don't laugh...you can use `KDE` on `Windows` ;)